# SQL error Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

I have an error

```
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).
```

when I call

```
select dbo.CheckProjectValidity(11, 9)
```

with this SQL function.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[CheckProjectValidity](@IdParent int, @IdStructure int)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
declare @Result bit;
if @IdParent=0
    set @Result = 0
    else
    if @IdParent=@IdStructure
        set @Result = 1
    else
        begin
            set @IdParent = (select st.IdParent from Structure st where st.IdParent=@IdParent);
            set @Result = dbo.CheckProjectValidity(@IdParent, @IdStructure)
        end
return @Result
END
```

The idea that I want to get the list of the Project from the tree.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result.

Comment: In addition to what [Nick said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60524897/533120), you may consider rewriting this as a recursive CTE, which can have arbitrary recursion depth (via `OPTION(MAXRECURSION)`). This can help if your hierarchy is naturally deeper than 32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your procedure is recursing infinitely because of this statement:

```
set @IdParent = (select st.IdParent from Structure st where st.IdParent=@IdParent)
```

which is effectively setting `@IdParent` to its existing value. You probably wanted to use something like:

```
set @IdParent = (select st.IdParent from Structure st where st.Id=@IdParent)
```

(I'm guessing that `IdParent` points to the `Id` value in another row)

Comment: . . .  Sub-query will return error if matching `id` has multiple `parent`

Comment: @YogeshSharma Yup, this should be rewritten to use `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma It's pretty unusual for a child to have multiple parents...

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic If either of you feel you have a better solution please post...

Comment: @Nick. . . Usually not. But, Structure table might have a more information associated with.

Comment: @YogeshSharma agreed. As I said in the answer, I was making a guess with regards to what was actually needed, although the error is caused by the statement I pointed out.